# How to get a HP Wi-Fi Touch Mouse X7000 working?

Tags: wireless, networking, mouse

I recently bought a very expensive 60 Dollar wireless mouse. This mouse connects to a Wireless Network Card, Instead of using a USB Dongle. I can't get this to work in Ubuntu 12.04. And I don't want to return it. How can I get it too work?

Comment: Just for general info, it doesn't work worth a crap in Windows 7 either. This is HP's attempt to make a Windows ME example in the Hardware Division. I had it working in WIn 7 8 and 10 but in all of them, it gave phantom clicks, opening ever blasted web page that I even touched with the cursor, it was and is still a nightmare device. I am thinking of tearing it apart and seeing what is inside, perhaps I can re purpose the innards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your HP X7000 mouse requires special drivers because it connects over Wi-Fi. HP **only has drivers for Windows 7** ([see here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=5169078&task=&)).

Comment: Thanks, I went out and exchanged it for another mouse with a USB Dongle.